# Writing to a file with specific X and Y coordinates for graphing in JAVA

Tags: java, file, output

I'm just wondering if its possible in java to write a character to a file on a specific line and column position?

I am writing a program to deal with stocks and Renko graphs, I can already interpret the input data and turn it into a string of one's and zero's. Where a 1 represents a move up and a 0 a move down. I just want to write this into a file using the "|" character to represent a Renko block.

For example if I had the string : 01011 I want to get the file to look like this:

```
        |
  |   |
|   |
```

I just don't know if there is a way to write on a specific line. Is what I want even possible? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no easy way to insert a character into textfile at given position. But is it really necessary?

Why don't you model your "drawing area" as a two-dimensional character array with a fixed height and width and prefilled with spaces? With this it is easy to put a character at a certain position. And when you are done with "drawing" you can write the contents of your two-dimensional array into a text file character by character.

Comment: Oh wow that's actually a perfect solution, it makes so much sense, Thank you.